# Understanding Chai's assertions (expect-style)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, automated-tests, mocha.js, chai

What's the difference here?

```
it("should be 5", () => {
  expect(num).equal(5);
});

it("should be 5", () => {
  expect(num).to.be.equal(5);
});
```

It does not make any difference if I use the first way or the second way. At least it seems so to me.

**What's the purpose of the ".to.be."?**

Is it just for having something which is more similar to an actual sentence? Or does it something functional?

Comment: They are just the chainable getters to improve the readability of your assertions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [doc](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/)

> The following are provided as chainable getters to improve the readability of your assertions.

Look this test case:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';

const num = 5;

describe('62770625', () => {
  it('should be 5', () => {
    expect(num).equal(5);
  });

  it('should be 5', () => {
    expect(num).to.be.equal(5);
  });

  it('should have members', () => {
    expect([{ a: 1 }]).deep.members([{ a: 1 }]); 
    expect([{ a: 1 }]).to.have.deep.members([{ a: 1 }]);
  });
});
```

Both of them work, but with these language Chains, we can get:

- Better readability
- Human friendly
- Good semantics